# ORDER BY specified order before GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

How would i order all rows by `ap_status` in this order `'n', 'p', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'x'` before grouping by `product_id`?

This query orders correctly when you remove the `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT `account_id`, `product_id`, `product_name`, `ap_status`, count(`ap_id`) as `num` 
FROM (accounts_products_view)
WHERE `account_id` = 13
/*GROUP BY `product_id`*/
ORDER BY FIELD(`ap_status`, 'n', 'p', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'x') desc
```

So i tried using `HAVING` after viewing some similar questions but, this is not working before the group by either

```
SELECT account_id, product_id, product_name, ap_status, count(ap_id) as num,
CASE
WHEN ap_status = 'n' then 1
WHEN ap_status = 'p' then 2
WHEN ap_status = 'd' then 3
WHEN ap_status = 'c' then 4
WHEN ap_status = 'b' then 5
WHEN ap_status = 'x' then 6
END as `order`

FROM (accounts_products_view)
WHERE `account_id` = 13
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING `order` = MIN(`order`)
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Comment: Maybe you could use your ORDER BY query as a sub query of another query, which uses GROUP BY on its result. Or use a temp table or sth.

Comment: show us your query. Anyway, if you're gonna grouping, and applicate an aggregate function, you don't need order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to try:

```
SELECT *, count(`ap_id`) as `num` FROM (
        SELECT `account_id`, `product_id`, `product_name`, `ap_status`, `ap_id`
        FROM (accounts_products_view)
        WHERE `account_id` = 13
        /*GROUP BY `product_id`*/
        ORDER BY FIELD(`ap_status`, 'n', 'p', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'x') desc
    ) as res GROUP BY product_id
```

but keep in mind it is INCORRECT!. If you use group by, then either you need to use aggregate function, like SUM() for example or specify the field in group by as well. In your example the fields that you might correctly retreive are product_id and nothing else. Because of MySQL bug or something you don't get exception on this query, but in postgresql you will get exception. 
If you have 2 rows with the same product_id and different ap_status, in theory you are not able to say which one should be returned by the query. I guess you have figured out that in MySQL the first row will be returned, that is why you want to order the rows before executing group by. Keep in mind that this is incorrect and very hackish.

Comment: This work perfectly, however, the `count(ap_id)` causes an error due to the `group by` being outside, is there a way of getting this aswell? I tried moving it onto the outer `SELECT` but this errored also Thank you :)

Comment: I added `SELECT *,count(ap_id)` and `ap_id` to the inner `SELECT` and this works error free. It might be hackish but i won't tell if you don't!

Comment: @JPickup ah right, my bad - I haven't seen count(ap_status), I will update the answer